# JasperReport replaces russian words with symbols ___

Tags: jasper-reports

i have issue with uploading a report to excel from jasper . My report has russian letters in the title and when i download it these letters are replaced by _______ ( look at the  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1RYE.png) ) .
This happens with all reports which has russian symbols . What can i do to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay , i got the solution . You need to replace your resource-id to eng symbols. But resource-id READ ONLY. You can connect to your jasper database and write this select:

```
select * from jiresource
```

you need "name" column. It's varchar(200) by default, but you can increase it as much as you wish. Then you need to find your report name and change it with english symbols. update table and enjoy .

Also if you dont wanna use database, you can create new JRMX file with right name/resource id , but its even more labor intensive .